# Remove 4xx handled errors from new relic Django project

Tags: django, newrelic

I am looking at a way to remove 4xx errors from my newrelic error rate reporting for a Django project.
It's a standard installation of new relic and Django framework.

Any help appreciated for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update your new relic config file to ignore these errors.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/configuration/python-agent-configuration#error-collector-settings

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter in your logging settings that changes the level of the 4xx errors. I've done this for 404 errors:

```
def change_404_level_to_INFO(record):
    if record.status_code == 404:
        record.levelname = 'INFO'
    return True

LOGGING = {
    ...,
    'filters': {
        'change_404_to_info': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': change_404_level_to_INFO,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        ...  # your newrelic handler
    },
    'loggers': {
        # Root logger"
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['newrelic', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
            'filters': ['change_404_to_info']
        },
    }
```